# Nested areas Magnolia

Tags: java, freemarker, magnolia

Well I'm making my own module, and looking to create a nested area with some children. At moment I'm creating my own nest like

```
<div id="feedGroup">
   [@cms.area name="example"/]
   [@cms.area name="feed"/]
</div>
```

One of my areas:

```
@Area("example")
    @AvailableComponentClasses({Example.class})
    public static class ExampleArea {

        @RequestMapping("/main/example")
        public String render() {
            return "pages/areas/example.ftl";
        }
    }
```

My ftl example:

```
[@cms.component content=component/]
```

My ftl feed:

```
[#list components as component]
    [@cms.component content=component/]
[/#list]
```

What I wanted to do (following this [link](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Structuring+page+areas)):

```
@Area("feed")
@Controller
@AvailableComponentClasses({ContentFeed.class})
public static class ContentFeedArea {

    @Area("example")
    @AvailableComponentClasses({Example.class})
    public static class ExampleArea {

        @RequestMapping("/main/example")
        public String render() {
            return "pages/areas/example.ftl";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/main/contentFeed")
    public String render() {
        return "pages/areas/contentFeed.ftl";
    }
}
```

It's giving me the error: The 'content' parameter was passed but not or wrongly specified. Can someone enlighten me or guide me how to it properly?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC area can't have nested area as it's immediate children.

To achieve desired result:

- define top area as being single-component area (possibly have that component even auto-generated so it's always in) and
- in above defined component, define the nested area you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you defined nested areas only in your controller. You should also nest them in the templates:

```
<div id="feedGroup">
    [@cms.area name="feed"/]
</div>
```

Content of `pages/areas/contentFeed.ftl`:

```
<div>
   [@cms.area name="example"/]       
</div>
```

The template `pages/areas/example.ftl` should be:

```
[#list components as component]
    [@cms.component content=component/]
[/#list]
```